# Why does my image upload successfully in Postman form-data, but not in my react code?

Tags: reactjs, redux, postman, form-data, mern

I was following Academind's tutorial on image uploads with node & multer here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=srPXMt1Q0nY

And as predicted, his code worked just fine for me. However, as soon I switched from Postman to my React code, I began to get an error that the req.file.path of the image is undefined. How can I get the image to post correctly to my back end? Here is the faulty code:

We start with the file input and the submit button.

```
            <label htmlFor="profilePic">Profile Picture</label>
        <input type="file" name="profilePic" className="inputfile" onChange={this.newFile}/>

        <section className="submit-form">
          <span onClick={this.submitForm}>
            <p>SUBMIT</p>
          </span>
        </section>
```

There are other inputs like textareas, but they work just fine so I left those out. Anyways, I capture the inputs and set them to state.

```
      //Set text values to state
  newValue = e => this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });

  newFile = e => this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.files[0] });

  submitForm = () => {
    let profileData = {
      username: this.state.username,
      bio: this.state.bio,
      alignment: this.state.alignment,
      location: this.state.location,
      skills: this.state.skills,
      origin: this.state.origin,
      profilePic: this.state.profilePic
    };

    this.props.createProfile(profileData, this.props.history);
  };
```

Create profile is an action that posts the data using redux.

```
    // Create Profile
export let createProfile = (profileData, history) => dispatch => {
  axios
    .post("/api/profile", profileData)
    .then(res => history.push("/dashboard"))
    .catch(err => dispatch({ type: GET_ERRORS, payload: err.response.data }));
};
```

Anyways, can you guys tell me why it posts with the form-data on Postman but not React?

Comment: Are you applying redux-thunk middleware?

Comment: Is your action creator properly binded with the thunk's dispatch?

Comment: @FelipeLanza I'm not sure if it's correctly done, as I'm following a tutorial. Please see the code here: github.com/Matiny/capebook/blob/master/client/src/store.js